# Find out if my macbook pro has USB3?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb-3

How can I find out if my macbook pro has USB3?

Im considering getting a USB3 to video convertor so I cant connect a 2nd monitor to my mac. Ive read that USB3 is better than USB2 but I cant figure out if I have it or not.

Answer (score 7):

Can also be done on the mac itself.

About this mac / more info / system report / USB

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://support.apple.com/specs/ - click on Browse Tech Specs by Product and enter your 
serial number. The tech spec will tell you what you have.

And USB2.0 is enough to do video output. Just make sure whatever brand you got has MAC support.

Note: Don't expect to be able to play anything fast moving / gaming on the 2nd monitor tho.

USB3.0 is faster in comparison to USB2.0 yes but there is no guarantee it can cope to display 2nd monitor without lag. If you are using 2nd monitor only for work purposes then you won't feel any difference / movement lag.

Also, USB to DVI (in Australia) that our company had bought before (for a PC) cost around $70. Your Mini DisplayPort to DVI/VGA should only cost around $35-$40. If you still have free (and working Mini DisplayPort use those first as those are specifically designed for graphic / monitor display rather than using USB to DVI/VGA/HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

If the ports on the machine are blue-ish in colour then it is USB3

[image: usb 3.0 cable] note colour inside the metal casing.

The use of blue pantone thermoplastics in USB 3.0 connectors is recommended on systems with a mix of USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: Do you mean the ports on my laptop or of the USB cables? I need to figure out what my laptop ports have.

Comment: in laptop also it will be in blue color as in the cable.if you are having black it will be 2.0

Comment: Apples MacBook Pro USB ports, even if USB 3, do not have blue coloured ports, there are multiple ways of checking via system utilities in utilities found in your application directory, it would also be stated under expansions on the box it came in